# Block matrix with eigenvalues on the unit circle

Tags: linear-algebra

There are two symmetry matrixes $P, Q\in \mathbb R^N$.

Define $A=\begin{bmatrix}P & Q\\I^{N\times N }& 0^{N\times N } \end{bmatrix}$.

If the eigenvalues of A $|\lambda|<1$, whant kind of constrain should be put on P and Q.

I only find some theory about such a matric $\begin{bmatrix}P & Q\\0^{N\times N }& I^{N\times N } \end{bmatrix}$. Unfortunately, it is not my case.

In my case, $P=\frac{2+a}{1+a}I-(\frac{ab+\theta ab}{1+a})M$ and $Q=\frac{\theta abM-1}{1+a}$, where $a, b, \theta $ are constants.

I am thinking if $\|A\|_2$ is less than 1, what should $a,b \theta$ be? I know this is a very important subject, like http://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat461/lecture17.pdf. But I did not find a answer from this document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\rho(A)\le\|A\|$ for every matrix norm, and $\|A\|_b:=\|S^{-1}AS\|_a$ is a matrix norm whenever $\|\cdot\|_a$ is a matrix norm and $S$ is nonsignular. By combining known matrix norms with similarity transform, one can always obtain a sufficient condition for $\rho(A)<1$ in the form of $\|S^{-1}AS\|<1$.

For instance, suppose $A$ satisfies the condition $\color{red}{\|\pmatrix{P&Q}\|_\infty<1}$, where $\|X\|_\infty=\max_i\sum_j|x_{ij}|$ is the maximum row sum norm. Then we get
$$
\|A\|:=\left\|S^{-1}AS\right\|_\infty<1\ \text{ with }\ S=\pmatrix{I\\ &(1+\epsilon)I}.
$$

Alternatively, if $\color{red}{Q \text{ is positive definite and } \operatorname{trace}(P^2)+2\operatorname{trace}(Q)<1}$, then $A$ is similar to $B=\pmatrix{P&Q^{1/2}\\ Q^{1/2}&0}$ and $\|B\|_F^2<1$. Hence $\rho(A)=\rho(B)\le\|B\|_F<1$.

Comment: Thank you. You mean $\rho(A)<1 \rightarrow \|S^{-1}AS\|<1 $

Comment: @Vivian NO. I mean $\|S^{-1}AS\|<1\Rightarrow\rho(A)<1$.

Comment: hi. What does ':=' mean? And how should I choose $a ,b $ in the following equation? $\|A\|_b:=\|S^{-1}AS\|_a$. What I try to solve is actually the 2 norm. I am also consider this problem.

Comment: @Vivian ':=' simply means "defined by". The symbol is borrowed from the assignment operator in the Pascal programming language. $a$ and $b$ are not numbers. $\|\cdot\|_a$ and $\|\cdot\|_b$ means two matrix norms. Given a matrix norm -- let's call it norm "a", we can define a new matrix norm -- say, norm "b" -- with any invertible matrix $S$ by the formula $\|A\|_b := \|S^{-1}AS\|_a$.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I know the definition of matrix norm, e.g. $a=2$. I am wondering if $b=2$, then $a=?$

Comment: @Vivian I repeat, $a$ and $b$ are not numbers. The symbols $\|\cdot\|_a$ and $\|\cdot\|_b$ here simply mean two matrix norms. They are not necessarily $p$-norms.

Comment: I am sure I know what you mean. But thanks for repeating.